# Detect if phone's keyboard is slid out

Tags: android, keyboard, hardware

I'd like to set focus to an EditText and automatically bring up the virtual keyboard in certain situations.  However, if a phone's hardware keyboard is slid out, I wouldn't want to.  Is there any way to detect whether or not a phone's hardware keyboard (if one exists) is slid out?  Or is there some functionality of the EditText that will handle all this for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().hardKeyboardHidden==Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO)
    {
    //do stuff
    }
```

To dive deeper, triggering OnConfigurationChanged on keyboard slide is explained in [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)